# How to know how many arguments can be used for compiling vim totally?

Tags: vim

My vim was compiled with the following  configure.

```
./configure   --prefix=/usr/local/           \
                       --with-features=huge  \
                       --enable-multibyte    \
                       --enable-cscope=yes   \
                       --enable-perlinterp=yes     \
                       --enable-rubyinterp=yes     \
                       --with-ruby-command=/usr/bin/ruby     \
                       --enable-luainterp=yes                \
                       --enable-pythoninterp=yes             \
                       --enable-python3interp=yes            \
                       --enable-tclinterp=yes                \
                       --enable-gui=gtk3                     \
                       --enable-cscope                       \
                       --enable-xim                          \
                       --enable-fontset                      \
                       --with-x --with-compiledby=$USER
```

How to know how many arguments can be used for compiling vim totally?
And almost same puzzle,how to know how many arguments can be used for compiling ffmpeg totally?
By what method?
Is there a sentence describing that there are xxxx arguements for compling vim such as ..... in some manul?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the list of all arguments simply with the help command :

```
:help feature-list
```